# Arranging points on a 2D surface in a cost minimizing optimal way

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory

I have a set of nodes. All of the nodes are connected by undirected weighted edges. The total weight for all of a node's edges always equals 1. 
Now I want to arrange the nodes on a two dimensional surface (with a diameter of `d`) in optimal way.

`Node A` is arranged in an optimal way to `Node B` if the distance from A to B is
 `(1-weightOfEdge)*diameterOfSurface`. (Ex: if the edge has the weight 1 then the distance between them should be 0. If the node has the weight 0 the distance between them should be `diameterOfSurface`.)

Obviously theres no way that I can arrange all of my nodes so that this condition holds. So I will define a cost function. The cost being the difference between the actual distance between A and B and the optimal distance between A and B. (Could be a bit more complicated too, like the difference squared to make the cost of being a total outlier higher)

The total cost of an arrangement of all nodes is the sum of the costs for each node.

I want to find THE optimal solution. (there could be more than one optimal solution, THE optimal solution just means that there are no other solutions with a lesser cost)

I first thought about using an iterative algorithm to arrive at an optimal solution, but quickly realized that by just iteratively moving the points I won't get an optimal solution because I can't move through valleys that might later lead to a better solution.

Then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346038/algorithm-for-placing-nodes-on-a-circle-considering-their-distance-to-eachother) that is similar and suggest that I generate random arrangements and then choose the best of them. And then do random arrangements from the best solution again etc. until I arrive a solution with a low cost. However this won't generate or prove that I have THE optimal solution.

Is there a way to find THE optimal solution? And if there is no way, why?
Hypothetically one could just look at all of the possible combinations and choose the best one (only if we use coordinates with a limited precision). But that is practically impossible. If we can't practically find THE best solution, is there a way to find a solution that is very close to the best and is provable to be very close to the best? (Whereby we could define very close as less than 10% off or something) And if not, is there a way to find a solution that has for example 90% chance to being less than 10% off from the best?

Edit: I'm looking for an algorithm that can compute a solution for about a few thousand points in a reasonable amount of time (less than a few hours on a modern mac) that can find the best solution or that can find a solution which is provable to be for example less than 10% off from the best solution or that is provable to have for example 90% chance of being less than 10% off from the best solution.

Comment: Well. If an problem is decidable / computable, there is always a way to solve it globally (you already showed a way). The question is just: can it be done efficiently. This problem is **non-convex** i think, which makes it very hard. (i think it's np-hard). I would try to formulate it as convex-concave problem. There are very robust heuristics (if the formulation is possible, what i think)

Comment: @sasha Thanks. I edited the question for what kind of algorithm and solution I'm looking for.

Comment: If the problem has some negative approximation results, which i think is possible (but i don't know), there is no algorithm which gives you the characteristics described in your edit (unless P=NP). At least the general problem without assumptions about instance-statistics.

Comment: Is this related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling?

Comment: The most popular way to solve this is to use a [force-based layouting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). But the optimization procedure can easily get stuck in local minima, as you already noticed. Maybe [Spectral Graph Layouting](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/data/acha.read.w12/koren-graph-drawing.pdf) is worth a try.